# Relative XPath Pagination for ASP Generated Results With No Next Button [Octoparse]

Tags: xpath, pagination, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape a government site that serves results paginated with no next button in Octoparse.

[Example of the Pagination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wwRG.png)

Is there a non-messy way to format a relative XPath so that it clicks the next pages in order?

```
Page One = .//*[@id='datagrid_results']/tbody/tr[42]/td/a[1]
Page Two = .//*[@id='datagrid_results']/tbody/tr[42]/td/a[2]
```

I've tried the Octoparse tutorials, but they only mention how to loop in situations where there is a next button. Is this a situation where I am better off using Selenium?

Comment: Yes, Octoparse is good for simple things but those aspx forms are too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with concurrent scripts running, which is fine since Octoparse limits things to 20,000 results for any one scrape. What I did was copy a script, and then insert a click to the second page of results, pages 41-80. Then I copied that script and added a second click to the third page of results, 81-120...and so on. It worked without doing anything else as the relative XPath was exactly the same.